# How to loop through a predefined list of variable and mutate many new columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

My objective is to read the variables from a list and compute new variables as stated in the list. The original list contains hundreds of variables.

For illustration purposes, I will use the example below. Let's say I have a list of variables with 3 columns with example below.

```
alist <- tibble(
  numerator = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp"),
  denominator = c("wt", "drat", "wt"),
  newvar = c("mpg_wt", "cyl_drat", "disp_wt")
)
```

Note that the denominator `wt` was purposely in the data twice. Because using `across` function failed when there was a duplicating column name.

How to pass this list into the `mtcars` table and mutate the new column as in the `alist` above with each new column name as in `newvar` and the formula for mutating new column is  `numerator` /`denominator`?

The desired output as below.
[image: Screenshot-2023-12-21-at-9-39-18-am.png]

Answer (score 7):

You could use `with`:

```
 mtcars %>%
    mutate(with(alist, set_names(.[numerator]/.[denominator], newvar)))

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   mpg_wt
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 8.015267
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 7.304348
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 9.827586
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 6.656299
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 5.436047
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 5.231214
                  cyl_drat   disp_wt
Mazda RX4         1.538462  61.06870
Mazda RX4 Wag     1.538462  55.65217
Datsun 710        1.038961  46.55172
Hornet 4 Drive    1.948052  80.24883
Hornet Sportabout 2.539683 104.65116
Valiant           2.173913  65.02890
```

---

In base R do:

```
cbind(mtcars,
    with(alist, setNames(mtcars[numerator]/mtcars[denominator], newvar)))
```

Comment: Really nice and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `bind_cols` and `purrr::pmap` to loop over the rows of `alist`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  # Only the head for the reprex
  head(5) %>%
  bind_cols(
    purrr::pmap(alist, \(numerator, denominator, newvar) {
      .|>
        mutate("{newvar}" := .data[[numerator]] / .data[[denominator]],
          .keep = "none"
        )
    })
  )
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   mpg_wt
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 8.015267
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 7.304348
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 9.827586
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 6.656299
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 5.436047
#>                   cyl_drat   disp_wt
#> Mazda RX4         1.538462  61.06870
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     1.538462  55.65217
#> Datsun 710        1.038961  46.55172
#> Hornet 4 Drive    1.948052  80.24883
#> Hornet Sportabout 2.539683 104.65116
```

**EDIT** Here is one approach to make this work using `%>%` inside `pmap`:

```r
mtcars %>%
  # Only the head for the reprex
  head(5) %>%
  bind_cols(
    purrr::pmap(alist, \(numerator, denominator, newvar, .data) {
      .data %>%
        mutate("{newvar}" := .data[[numerator]] / .data[[denominator]],
          .keep = "none"
        )
    }, .data = .)
  )
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   mpg_wt
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 8.015267
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 7.304348
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 9.827586
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 6.656299
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 5.436047
#>                   cyl_drat   disp_wt
#> Mazda RX4         1.538462  61.06870
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     1.538462  55.65217
#> Datsun 710        1.038961  46.55172
#> Hornet 4 Drive    1.948052  80.24883
#> Hornet Sportabout 2.539683 104.65116
```

Comment: Mhh, I am unable to run this code. ..

Comment: @Onyambu Hm. You are right. I just fixed it. Weird. This works with |> inside `pmap` but not with %>%.

Comment: @user2360397 Me too. No clue what's the issue.

Comment: Just made an edit and added an approach to make the code work using %>%.

Comment: It now works. You can even have `{mutate(., "{newvar}" := ...)}` instead of using `.data` or even `{{.}%>%mutate("{newvar}" := ...)}`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a simple base subsetting approach:

```
mtcars[,alist[['newvar']]] <-
    mtcars[,alist[['numerator']]]/mtcars[,alist[['denominator']]]

> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   mpg_wt cyl_drat   disp_wt
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 8.015267 1.538462  61.06870
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 7.304348 1.538462  55.65217
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 9.827586 1.038961  46.55172
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 6.656299 1.948052  80.24883
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 5.436047 2.539683 104.65116
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 5.231214 2.173913  65.02890
```